# MongoDB Aggregation with sum of array values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with the following data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5516d416d0c2323619ddbca8"),
    "date" : "28/02/2015",
    "driver" : "user1",
    "passengers" : [
        {
            "user" : "user2",
            "times" : 2
        },
        {
            "user" : "user3",
            "times" : 3
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5516d517d0c2323619ddbca9"),
    "date" : "27/02/2015",
    "driver" : "user2",
    "passengers" : [
        {
            "user" : "user1",
            "times" : 2
        },
        {
            "user" : "user3",
            "times" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

And I would like to perform aggregation so that I will know for a certain passenger, times it was with a certain driver, in my example it would be:
for user1: `[{ driver: user2, times: 2}]`
for user2: `[{ driver: user1, times: 2}]`
for user3: `[{ driver: user1, times: 3}, {driver: user2, times:2}]`

Im quite new with mongo and know how to perform easy aggregation with sum, but not when its inside arrays, and when my subject is itself in the array.
what is the appropriate way to perform this kind of aggregation, and in more specific, how I perform it in express.js based server?

Comment: Have a look at $unwind: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To achieve your needs with aggregation framework, the first pipeline stage will be a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operation on the passenger in question that matches the documents with the user in the passenger array, followed by the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operation which deconstructs the passengers array from the input documents in the previous operation to output a document for each element.  Another **`$match`** operation on the deconstructed array follows that further filters the previous document stream to allow only matching documents to pass unmodified into the next pipeline stage, which is projecting the required fields with the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator. So essentially your aggregation pipeline for `user3` will be like:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
     {
        "$match": {
            "passengers.user": "user3"
        }
     },
     {
         "$unwind": "$passengers"
     },
     {
        "$match": {
            "passengers.user": "user3"
        }
     },
     {
         "$project": {
             "_id": 0,
            "driver": "$driver",
            "times": "$passengers.times"
        }
     }
])
```

**Result**:

```js
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "driver" : "user1",
            "times" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "driver" : "user2",
            "times" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

***UPDATE***:

For grouping duplicates on drivers with different dates, as you mentioned you can do a [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operation just before the last **`$project`** pipeline stage where you compute the total passengers times using the **`$sum`** operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     {
        "$match": {
            "passengers.user": "user3"
        }
     },
     {
         "$unwind": "$passengers"
     },
     {
        "$match": {
            "passengers.user": "user3"
        }
     },
     {
         "$group": {
             "_id": "$driver", 
             "total": {
                 "$sum": "$passengers.times"
             }
         }
     },
     {
         "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "driver": "$_id",
            "total": 1
        }
     }
])
```

**Result**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "total" : 2,
            "driver" : "user2"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 3,
            "driver" : "user1"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very close to my needs (it didnt group duplicates of drivers from different dates). I ended up using a `$group: {"_id": "$driver",               "total": {$sum: "$passengers.times"}}`,