# Can not get $sum in aggregate function in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here's my data format :

```
"request" : {
    "_id" : 1003,
    "user" : {
        "username" : "",
        "password" : "",
        "_id" : 1111,
        "gender" : "male",
       },
    "request" : {
        "merchantid" : "TA456",
        "txnAmount" : 18000,
        "fee" :0,
        "IssuerID" : "18801111",
        "bankID" : "888888",
    }

},
 "confirmation" : true
```

}`

I can not get the sum of 'request.request.txnAmount' group by 'request.user._id'.

Here's my query:

```
db.getCollection('megabank_response').aggregate(
[ {        $group : {
           _id : "request.user._id",
           totalPrice: { $sum: "request.request.txnAmount"},
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }
   ])
```

And get the result :

```
{
    "_id" : "request.user._id",
    "total Price" : 0,
    "count" : 4.0
}
```

Can anyone help me why my query cannot calculate the sum?

Comment: `txnAmount` is a `String` convert it number and then check your aggregation query

Comment: I've already tried that and the result remain the same

Answer (score 1):

You seem to missing the $ symbol in the group aggregation function.

```
db.megabank_response.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: "request.user._id",
    ss: {
      $sum: "request.request.txnAmount"
    }
  }
}]);
```

gives: `{ "_id" : "request.user._id", "ss" : 0 }`

But the correct answer is:

```
db.megabank_response.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: "$request.user._id",
    ss: {
      $sum: "$request.request.txnAmount"
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I've just understood how it works by now

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figured out the query using answer from [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319799/mongodb-aggregation-with-sum-of-array-values).
However, my query is stil a little bit too messy. Any ways to optimize it?

```
db.getCollection('megabank_response').aggregate([
 {
    "$match": {
        "request.user._id": 1111
    }
 },
   {  
     "$group":{
       _id : "request.user._id",
       totalPrice: { $sum: '$request.request.txnAmount'},
       count: { $sum: 1 }
   }
 }
```

])

Result:

```
{
"_id" : "request.user._id",
"totalPrice" : 62000,
"count" : 3.0
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
db.getCollection('megabank_response').aggregate([{        
    $group: {
        _id : "request.user._id",
        totalPrice: { $sum: "$request.request.txnAmount"},
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `totalPrice: { $sum: "$txnAmount"}` to display the sum of your transaction amount. I was working on the `GET` request of Total Sales in the `e-shop` that I developed, and I had faced the same issue. Just for your reference, here is my code:

```
//GET total sales data for the ADMIN
router.get('/get/totalsales', async(req, res) => {
    const totalSales = await Order.aggregate([
        { $group: { _id: null, totalSales : { $sum: '$totalPrice' }}} // Use $totalPrice instead of totalPrice
    ])

    if(!totalSales) {
        return res.status(400).send('The sales cannot be generated')
    }
    res.send({totalSales: totalSales})
})
```

Hope this helps :)